# A question about configuring stablelines3 on ubuntu18.04

Tags: stable-baselines

I have a question about stablebaselines3 configuration on ubuntu18.04. First I created a python3.7 virtual environment, then I downloaded gym0.26.2, successfully installed; then I used pip install stable-baselines3[extra], but there was a problem.

Some answers on the Internet said that it was a setuptools version problem, so I updated my setuptools version to 47.1.0, because I had configured a similar environment before, which used The version of setuptools is 47.1.0, I don’t know how to solve it, I hope to get your help, thank you very much

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.